# Dict Comprehension with index

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, dictionary-comprehension

How to obtain the equivalent result of this code using dictionary comprehension?

```
dict_sq = dict()
i = 0
for y in range(grid_height):
    for x in range(grid_height):
        dict_sq[i] = (x, y)
        i = i + 1
```

> {0: (0, 0), 1: (1, 0), 2: (2, 0), 3: (0, 1), 4: (1, 1), 5: (2, 1), 6: (0, 2), 7: (1, 2), 8: (2, 2)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative method from the other answer, I used list comprehension with `enumerate` to map it to a dict.

```
dict(enumerate((x, y) for y in range(grid_height) for x in range(grid_height)))
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you want (iterating over `x` and `y` and calculating `i = x + grid_height * y` from those):

```
grid_height = 3
dct = {x + grid_height * y:
           (x, y) for y in range(grid_height) for x in range(grid_height)}
```

or you could go the other way round (iterating over `i` and getting `x = i//grid_height` and )`y = i%grid_height` from that):

```
dct = {i: (i//grid_height, i%grid_height) for i in range(grid_height**2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.product` to create one iterator iterating over both ranges, then `enumerate` to add indexes to that iterator:

```
from itertools import product

dict_sq = {i: (x, y)
           for (i, (y, x)) in enumerate(product(range(grid_height), range(grid_height)))}
```

Since the ranges are the same, you could use `repeat=2` instead of writing the range twice:

```
from itertools import product

dict_sq = {i: (x, y)
           for (i, (y, x)) in enumerate(product(range(grid_height), repeat=2))}
```